# [NSString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@""" withString:@""""];

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring

I have an `NSString` and want to save it in `CSV` format. Because of this, I am replacing all `"` with `""`. I tried the following code but the compiler reports an error for it.

```
newString = [oldstring stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@""" withString:@""""];
```

where oldstring is `11th ave, "L&T", Khar`. oldstring is set from user input.

How can I end up with newString set to `11th ave, ""L&T"", Khar`?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to escape double quotes (`"`) inside your string:

```
newString =  [oldString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"\"\""];
```